# Transform div elements into ul?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got the following code (a navigation tree):

```
<div class="tr">
        <div class="navigationl1">Preface, revisions, and safety
           <div class="navigationl2">
              Preface
              <div class="navigationl3">
                 <div class="navigationl4">
                    <div class="navigationl5">
                       <div class="documenttitle">Service documentation</div>
                       <div class="documenttitle">About this documentation</div>
                       <div class="documenttitle">About this product</div>
                       <div class="documenttitle">Training</div>
                       <div class="documenttitle">Trademarks</div>
                       <div class="documenttitle">Contact</div>
                       <div class="documenttitle">Feedback</div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
          <div class="navigationl2">Revisions
              <div class="navigationl3">Service documentation
                 <div class="navigationl4">
                    <div class="navigationl5">
                       <div class="documenttitle">Version 1.0</div>
                    </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="navigationl4">Revision history
                    <div class="navigationl5">
                       <div class="documenttitle">Version 0.0</div>
                    </div>
                 </div>
              </div>
           </div>
```

I would like to transform this div elements into li elements of an ul, by keeping the structure.

I made this jquery code from various topics on this forum, but it does not work at all:

```js
jQuery.fn.closestPrev = function(selector) {
    var current = $(this);
    var abort = false;
    while (!abort) {
        if (current.prev().length == 0) {
            abort = true;
            current = $([]);
        }
        else {
            current = current.prev();
            if (current.is(selector)) {
                abort = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return current;
};
$(".tr").find(".navigationl1.navigationl2.navigationl3.navigationl4.navigationl5.documenttitle:eq(1)").wrapInner("<div class='wrapingClass'></div>") ;
$(".tr").find(".wrapingClass").unwrapUntil(7).wrap("<li class='LiClass'><ul><li><ul><li><ul><li><ul><li></li></ul></li></ul></li></ul></ul></li></li>");
$(".tr").wrapInner("<ul id='org'></ul>");
i = 0;
$('.LiClass').closestPrev('a').each(function(){   
        FirstA = $(this).first();
    $('.LiClass:eq('+i+') li:eq(1)').prepend(FirstA);  
            i++ ;
    });
i = 0;
$('.LiClass').closestPrev('a').each(function(){   
        FirstA = $(this).first();
    $('.LiClass:eq('+i+')').prepend(FirstA);  
            i++ ;
    });
```

Do you know what is wrong with this code and why the div are not turned into ul/li ?

Here's the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0m8bxp65/2/

Thanks a lot in advance !

Comment: Hi. are you getting any errors in the console? (in developer tools)

Comment: Hi Sarah ! What kind of developer tols can I use ? I only tried on JSFiddle (I'm a total beginner in jQuery, first time I used it is today).

Comment: Ok :) If you put your code in a html document and open it in a browser (I am using chrome). There's a settings icon in the top right hand corner of the browser. Click that and go to "more tools" then "developer tools". Then a section will open at the bottom of your browser and the items will include: Elements, Console, Sources etc. Choose "Console" and you will see errors there.

Comment: Actually u can see the console in the JSFiddle if you go up to the settings icon in the browser there. and follow the rest of the steps i said.

Comment: I opened the console on Chrome, but I do not understand where should I place my JS code ?

Comment: you can just open the console in your JS Fiddle browser (where you already have all your code). It will show your errors there.

Comment: I'm unsure of where exactly you would like each ul and each li to be so could you post the HTML code in the exact format that you would like to convert it to?

Comment: I added some information in the answer below. ;)

Comment: That's great thanks. I just had a look and I'm pretty sure that you can't have li's directly descending li's. Let me try figure something out :)

Comment: Hey. Just want to point out you are trying to pass in "a" tags to your closestPrev function however as far as I can see there are no "a" tags in your html so the loops that you have as follows aren't doing anything: $('.LiClass').closestPrev('a').each(function(){ ...  }); ... I am not familiar with unwrapUntil.js but I've worked out a different way of converting your divs to uls and lis with jQuery if you want to see?

Comment: Indeed I realised that too late. Yes I would be glad to see your way !
On the meantime, I tried with this code. It works but it is not perfect, since empty nodes are still shown as <li> : http://jsfiddle.net/r5ueoL2f/

Comment: That new code you've done looks good. It's neater than mine. Here's mine: https://jsfiddle.net/sarahmonks/ncy3vb71/2/

Comment: Thanks for your help Sara :) I have managed to get rid of the unnecessary bullets by removing them totally with a CSS "list-style:none;". Now I am looking how to add an <input> tag inside the wrapinner, but it does not work. That will be my next challenge.

Comment: No probs. :) Good work. Sounds like your on your way :)

Answer (score 0):

I found this info on the console when running JSFiddle :)

```html
crbsrv.jsfiddle.net/ads/CKYIEKQ7.json?segment=placement:jsfiddlenet&callback=_carbonads_go:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
7Refused to execute script from '<URL>' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
fiddle.jshell.net/0m8bxp65/2/show/:1 Refused to execute script from 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jamesallardice/jquery.unwrapuntil/master/jquery.unwrapUntil.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
(index):1 Refused to execute script from 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jamesallardice/jquery.unwrapuntil/master/jquery.unwrapUntil.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
(index):1 Refused to execute script from 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jamesallardice/jquery.unwrapuntil/master/jquery.unwrapUntil.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
(index):1 Refused to execute script from 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jamesallardice/jquery.unwrapuntil/master/jquery.unwrapUntil.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
(index):1 Refused to execute script from 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jamesallardice/jquery.unwrapuntil/master/jquery.unwrapUntil.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
(index):1 Refused to execute script from 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jamesallardice/jquery.unwrapuntil/master/jquery.unwrapUntil.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
(index):1 Refused to execute script from 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jamesallardice/jquery.unwrapuntil/master/jquery.unwrapUntil.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
(index):54 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).find(...).unwrapUntil is not a function
    at (index):54
    at dispatch (jquery-1.9.1.js:3074)
    at elemData.handle (jquery-1.9.1.js:2750)
```

And the output I would like to get would be something like this:

```html
<ul class="tr">
  <li class="navigationl1">Preface, revisions, and safety
    <li class="navigationl2">Preface
      <li class="navigationl3">
        <li class="navigationl4">
          <li class="navigationl5">
            <li class="documenttitle">Service documentation</li>
            <li class="documenttitle">About this documentation</li>
            <li class="documenttitle">About this product</li>
            <li class="documenttitle">Training</li>
            <li class="documenttitle">Trademarks</li>
            <li class="documenttitle">Contact</li>
            <li class="documenttitle">Feedback</li>
          </li>
        </li>
      </li>
    </li>
  </li>
  <li class="navigationl2">Revisions
    <li class="navigationl3">Service documentation
      <li class="navigationl4">
        <li class="navigationl5">
          <li class="documenttitle">Version 1.0</li>
        </li>
      </li>
      <li class="navigationl4">Revision history
        <li class="navigationl5">
          <li class="documenttitle">Version 0.0</li>
        </li>
      </li>
    </li>
  </li>
</li>
```

I am not sure how multiple levels of li can be nested in an ul though.